# New to the MEAN stack, how to get data?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I'm programming for a college assignment and I've got no idea what I did wrong, so looking for pointers here.

So I'm trying to access events from a database and display them as thumbnails. Where am I going wrong?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" ng-repeat="event in EventCtrl.events" ng-controller="EventController as EventCtrl">
    <div class="thumbnail tile tile-medium">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-event-modal">
            <img id = "eventImg" src="/img/sports.png" alt="Sports">
        </a>
    </div>
```

Angular Controller:

```
angular.module('EventCtrl', []).controller('EventController', function($http) {
$http.get("/events")
.then(function(response) {
    this.events = {}
    this.events = response.data;
});
```

});

Node function:

```
app.get('/events', function(req, res){
    eventData = Event.find({}).toArray();
    res.render('events', eventData);
});
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in your console ? If yes, please post that too.

Comment: no bugs in the console

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should manipulate the $scope, and your view should interact with the scope.

Why don't try something like that

```
angular.module('EventCtrl', []).controller('EventController', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get("/events").then(function(response) {
    $scope.events = response.data;
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I just tried this and the {{events}} printed out my entire index file so the problem might be bigger than I thought. Somethings not right in the db maybe?

Comment: What do you mean with your entire index file? You are retrieving all the events from your database, aren't you? What happen if you type in your browser http://your-app/events ?

Comment: http://oi66.tinypic.com/2dgm7hi.jpg This happened. I think the somewhere in my server.js file, the index file gets passed instead of my event data. Very weird.

Comment: Yes, quite weird, sorry I can't be more useful.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Apparently "When you request a URL which cannot be found, sometimes the default 404 contents will be returned, which is the index.html page in this case. " So I have to doublecheck the routes.